# i want to find factorial of 'n' number of numbers in c++

Tags: c++

I want to find factorial of n number of numbers and it seems the code is right. But why does the program output a wrong answer?

**Sample input**

4

1

2

3

4

**Samplw Output**

1

2

6

24

See the output is correct but idk why the website says wrong answer?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int t, n, f;
  cin >> t;
  while (t > 0) {
    f = 1;
    cin >> n;
    while (n > 0) {
      f = f * n;
      n--;
    }
    cout << f << "\n";
    t--;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does the compiler say it’s wrong? Or do you mean when you run it the answer is wrong? What’s the input and output?

Comment: Which is wrong? Is 3! wrong should be 6. The `int` type can handle 12! but not 13!

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen i am submitting this code to a website which says my answer is wrong

Comment: @Eraklon how did you edited my question?... i mean  is there any feature to edit others question?

Comment: @AnishVijay See [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). Users with 2000 reputation or more are trusted to edit any question or answer. Any user can edit any question or answer but are normally subject to community approval. Information on editing can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: @AnishVijay We don't know what the input is.  What is `n` supposed to be?  Please clarify the question, as `n` could be anything.

Comment: @AnishVijay Run your code on your own system and see what inputs work and which don't. Update your question with what you find out.

Comment: I'm not sure why you chose those names, but ````t````, ````n```` nor ````f```` are telling a reading coder what they are meant to keep. Also, you could just as well use a ````for````-loop, since you know exactly how many times you'll be iterating.

Comment: What is the aim of the `while` in `t`?

Comment: @Eddymage -- I wish posters would get rid of that `t` loop.  It is meaningless to the question, as it usually means the number of test cases.

Comment: @AnishVijay -- Now what if `n` is 100?  Does your code handle numbers that big?  You should tell us what the maximum value of `n` is.

Comment: @Eddymage while loop for t is for test cases

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie there is  no constraint on n

Comment: @AnishVijay -- If there is no constraint on `n`, your code will never work properly for large `n`.  Find another way of computing factorials, possibly use Binet's formula.  You need to realize that these online coding websites give questions that have "easy", but naïve solutions that will fail when given large input.  Those sample input's you're showing are fool's gold.  Your solution cannot work for large `n`, and the goal is to see if you can do the research in figuring out how to compute large factorials.

Comment: @AnishVijay you still have not posted what the limit for `n` is. There *must be* a limit given in the website's problem description.

Comment: I meant to say "Stirling's Formula", not Binet's formula.  Binet's formula is used to calculate the Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 2):

use `long long int` instead of `int`.  if you need something accurate for large numbers use [`gmp`](https://gmplib.org/) instead.

Taking into account that factorial is positive you can also can use `unsigned long long` to enlarge 1 more bit of data (this does not help though in the case of factorial function, conforming to the series [A000142](https://oeis.org/A000142)).

This can accurately keep the result for maximum `ULLONG_MAX` ( 18446744073709551615=2^64-1), the biggest factorial in the limit of `long long` type is, conforming to the The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, [2432902008176640000](https://oeis.org/A000142), which is `factorial(20)`.

Comment: We need to know what the maximum value of `n` is in the input.  It may be something that has the answer go above `long long int`, and I don't think these websites that have these online coding questions allow `gmp` to be used.

Comment: @alinsoar what's gmp??

Comment: Here are a few GMP links [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library) and [https://gmplib.org/](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: Adding `unsigned` doesn't hurt. (don't know if we increase valid factorial with that BTW).

Comment: @AnishVijay Arithmetic without limitations and implemented fast.

Comment: @Jarod42 i added unsigned but it doesn't works.

Comment: @AnishVijay unsigned does not help -- long long type as well as unsigned long long helps until fact(20) and of course in printf() you need to instrument the printing with "%ll".